# getInitialProps is never executed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make a Twitter component that loads the tweet from the twitter API and displays its HTML, which will be a `<blockquote>` and a `<script>` tag.

The advantage of this, if server side rendered, is that it would work even if the user has privacy settings that block the call to the twitter script: the user will still get the blockquote, which is better than the current behavior (shows nothing).

So, my idea was to do something like this:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

function Tweet(props) {
  return <>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: props.__html
    }} />
    <p>here I am</p>
  </>
}

Tweet.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  console.log("here I am on the road again")
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=${ctx.tweetId}`)
  const json = await res.json()
  return { __html: json.html }
}

export default Tweet
```

And then on the pages use it like `<Tweet tweetId="blah" />`.

I found two problems with my idea though:

1. As per docs I cant access the tweetId property on `getInitialProps`
2. `getInitialProps` is never called. The `<p>here I am</p>` appears on the HTML and the log is never printed anywhere.

So, my question is: what I am doing wrong? Is this even possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages), `getInitialProps` can only be used to a page, and not in a component:

> `getInitialProps` can only be added to the default component exported by a page, adding it to any other component won't work.

Comment: any ideas of something else I can do?

Comment: Isn't `Tweet` the default component being exported there?

Comment: I would suggest you to move your data fetching on the page needed and on your page render feed your component with the data returned by the API

Comment: @JuanMarco the reason why there is a reference for `default export` on the paragraph above, is because a page (e.g. mypage.js) could have multiple exports and they just highlight the fact that only the `export default` of that file (mypage.js) will be able to use `getInitialiProps`.

Comment: I did it on the page component and it works, had to do some workarounds but it did work, thanks!